# how to proper cache a variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I have a rails App which displays always the company name on each page.
Since a logged in user can have multiple companies she belongs to. 
User and companies are stored in the db.
I use authlogic for the user management.

Now I do not want to hit the database on every postback or page change
What would be best practise to chache/store the company until the logged in users changes or the user selects a different company? Something like global instance vars for a given user.

I started with this in my application_controller

```
def current_company
  return @current_company if defined?(@current_company)
  @current_company = Account.includes(:users).where(:users =>current_company)
end
```

and I realized that I am still hitting the db...

Is the session the recommended way or what would be best practice for this...

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 2):

**||= way:**

```
def current_company
  @current_company ||= Account.includes(:users).where(:users =>current_company)
end
```

**memoize way:**

```
def current_company
  Account.includes(:users).where(:users =>current_company)
end
memoize :current_company
```

**Differences between this method and normal memoization with ||=**

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/memoize#447-Differences-between-normal-or-assign-operator

@tadman, you are right but from my point of view depends how complex its the method that you are trying to "cache". For simple cases I prefer ||=

Comment: The `||=` method is great for plain Ruby, but in Rails you may want to use the [memoize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/memoize) method as it's more flexible.

Comment: This applies only per page request? Or I am I wrong. When I hit refresh I hit the database... I want to define it in the Application_controller because it show on every page. Am I on the wrong path

Comment: @tadman: undeprecated link => http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Memoizable/memoize

Comment: Anything attached to an instance of your controller will be for one request only. Anything attached to the class will persist for the lifespan of the process. Note however this data is not shared between instances of Rails, of which there are usually several on any active site.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for
https://github.com/nkallen/cache-money

Comment: Looks good but does not support Rails 3 and I am targeting Rails 3... are you using it with rails 3?